# How to send SMS in C#

Tags: c#, sms

I want to integrate SMS service with the software I am developing, so that users could send SMS to their clients.

Comment: -1: This is very vague. Let us know what research you have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Subodh i know your question, i also want that software as i am a LIC agent, well that would help me in managing my clients and policies...

well for more answers, search on google with keyword -- "sms api"

Answer (score 5):

Really the question that you need to ask is, which SMS service would be easiest to integrate with C#. Most of them out there have Web APIs, which would be easy enough to tie in with a C# application.

A few example gateways:

http://www.mediaburst.co.uk/api/

http://www.zeepmobile.com/

http://www.messagemedia.co.uk/

Of course, to send SMS this way will cost money (usually in the form of credits with your chosen gateway). If you meant to ask how can you interact with a physical phone to send messages, well that would all depend on the phone, it's o/s and software available for it.

Comment: buddy, then answer to that question only

Comment: I've already given you the information you need to achieve the desired result - each of the mentioned gateways have their own API. You need to research them, find out which one is best suited to you/your client, and the implement the API in C#.

Comment: With regards to how you can interact with the Web via C#, look into the HttpWebRequest class.

Comment: You mean you're not going to do all the work for him Siedr? :-P Some folk are beyond help!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can get actual SMS integration by sending an email `('[phoneNumber]@[carrierDomainName]')`. This is how I integrated paging into my EventLog in the past. The cellphone domain name for each carrier shouldn't be too hard to determine. Verizon's is `vtext.com`.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder how many providers conform to this 'standard', or indeed allow this method of sending SMS.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways
More gateways in that link which follow this pattern/standard

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of SMS gateways:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want an API of sorts.  Check out the following libraries:

http://twit88.com/blog/2009/07/31/c-sms-library/

http://www.topshareware.com/mCore-.NET-SMS-Library-(LITE)-download-42284.htm

http://www.hillstone-software.com/hs_sms_dll_details.htm